# In or im with years and dates

Tags: article, time

When it comes to dates, I've seen both variants, like these:

> "Im Januar 2001 wurde das Video veröffentlicht..."
>
> "Im Jahr 1905 erschien seine Arbeit mit dem Titel..."
>
> "In 1980 schloss Microsoft eine Partnerschaft mit IBM..."

- Is it true that you should include the article when there is a noun (Januar, Jahr), and should not with just a number?
- Can one always use "*im*"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*In [Jahreszahl]* is not used in German. Well, I've seen it being used lately, but in my opinion that's an unidiomatic anglicism. This is from a [Duden Newsletter](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-13-06-08):

> In der Wirtschafts- und Werbesprache wird gelegentlich die aus dem
> englischsprachigen Raum stammende Verbindung der Präposition in mit
> einer Jahreszahl verwendet: Die Konsolidierung dieser
> Geschäftsbereiche wurde in 2003 abgeschlossen. Wenn in 2525 die
> Menschheit noch existiert  **Allerdings wird dieser Anglizismus nicht
> allgemein akzeptiert.** Als standardsprachlich gilt die Jahreszahl ohne
> Präposition oder die Fügung im Jahre + Jahreszahl: Die Konsolidierung
> dieser Geschäftsbereiche wurde [im Jahre] 2003 abgeschlossen. Wenn [im
> Jahre] 2525 die Menschheit noch existiert

Hence, this example is not correct:

> In 1980 schloss Microsoft eine Partnerschaft mit IBM.

Instead, use *im Jahr(e) [Jahreszahl]* or just *[Jahreszahl]*.

> Im Jahr 1980 schloss Microsoft eine Partnerschaft mit IBM.
>
> 1980 schloss Microsoft eine Partnerschaft mit IBM.

The latter doesn't work with months, however. You need the *im*. This is not correct:

> Januar 2001 wurde das Video veröffentlicht.

Comment: Thanks for a very details answer. I don't know why, but the variant without any preposition seems odd to me. How do you say it? Just a year without declension or something, and then the verb?

Comment: @Maxim: I can see why it seems odd, but this is correct and idiomatic. In some contexts it's definitely preferable to use *im Jahr*, e.g., if the year could be confused with another number ("2010 habe ich 2000 Euro verdient, 2011 3000" is not exactly incorrect but obviously really bad style.). Some might also say it's generally bad to start a sentence with just a year number, I personally don't really care. But *im Jahr* is never wrong, so just go with that if it helps you sleep at night. ;)

Comment: Wooh, **now** I'm going to sleep well! =)

Answer (score 5):

With months and seasons it's "im" (in dem). With years it's either "im Jahr XXXX" or nothing at all, as in

> Im Jahr 1980 schloss Microsoft eine Partnerschaft mit IBM
>
> 1980 schloss Microsoft eine Partnerschaft mit IBM

"In + year" is an adaptation of the english form, I think it's (still?) considered incorrect (which doesn't mean it's not used, of course).

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes (mostly)

> "Im Januar 2001 wurde das Video veröffentlicht..."
>   "Im Jahr 1905 erschien seine Arbeit mit dem Titel..."
>   "Im Sommer 2012 habe ich ein Praktikum bei..."

As being mentioned, it is possible to do

> "Im **Jahre** 1905 erschien seine Arbeit mit dem Titel..."

But don't do that if you are not certain about whether to do it or not. It sounds contrived even in written form.

Note that there is also this

> Bis wann ging dein Praktikum? - Bis August [letzten Jahres]

---

2) You can. `im` does not refer to a time within this period. It can be in the beginning, end or anytime between.

Additionally its e. g. possible to use

- `ab` / `bis`
- `vor` / `nach`

> Deutschland war bis Ende 1990 geteilt
>   Das war noch vor 1945